# Unresolved reference in Kotlin Android Studio fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to use this package https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player to play a youtube video. The error I'm getting is Unresolved reference: youTubePlayerView. I've never worked with fragments before so I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong? After declaring the button in the oncreateview I could set up a listener for it fine, but for some reason after declaring the youtubePlayerView I cant use it and it results in an unresolved reference. What should I do?

here's my code:

```
package com.srm325.recyclertest.ui.features.receivesong

import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.aliakberaakash.cutiehacksproject2020.R
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.searchsong_layout.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch

private const val BASE_URL =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyAcqsfnhOFIyIgX1auWR-SzjcTXOoc3MDE&part=snippet,id&order=viewCount&maxResults=1&q="

class receivefragment : Fragment() {
    companion object{
        const val GET_FROM_GALLERY = 3
    }
    lateinit var videostring: String
    lateinit var selectedImage:Uri
    lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage
    val db = Firebase.firestore

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receive_layout, container, false)
        val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = view.findViewById<YouTubePlayerView>(R.id.youtube_player_view)
        val uploadBtn: MaterialButton = view.findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn)
        return view
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)
            youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    var video123: String = "lOqy8cC72wA";
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(video123!!, 0f)


                }
            })

        }


    }

}
private fun requestData(urlstring: String): String? {
    return try {
        val response = arrayOfNulls<String>(1)
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        Thread {
            try {
                Log.d("START", "Starting GET")
                val url = URL(urlstring)
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.requestMethod = "GET"
                connection.connectTimeout = 5000
                connection.readTimeout = 5000
                connection.connect()
                Log.d("INFO", urlstring)
                Log.d("INFO", Integer.toString(connection.responseCode))
                Log.d("INFO", connection.responseMessage)
                val rd = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream))
                var content = ""
                var line: String
                while (rd.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    content += """
                        $line
                        
                        """.trimIndent()
                }
                response[0] = content
                Log.d("SUCCESS", response[0]!!)
                latch.countDown()
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Error Processing Get Request...")
                var i = 0
                while (i < ex.stackTrace.size) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", ex.stackTrace[i].toString())
                    i++
                }
                latch.countDown()
            }
        }.start()
        latch.await()
        response[0]
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you try to launch it from the fragment, not from the activity. Try to use `requireActivity().youTubePlayerView` instead.